# Mass Transit: Using AWS SQS and Job Consumers

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

Currently we're using Hangfire for scheduling and running long lived tasks. We need these tasks to be able to be retried in the event of an ungraceful shutdown, which Hangfire handles for us.

We're looking to try and move to a producer/consumer model and I've built a basic prototype with Masstransit and AWS SQS, but I have some concerns about how to handle the event of a task being processed during an ungraceful shutdown.

I understand that eventually the SQS visibility timeout will expire and the queued item will be picked up for processing again, but setting that timeout isn't trivial as the length of tasks can be quite varied and I'd prefer if the task could immediately resume/retry processing when the application starts up again.

I got reading about Job Consumers and they seemed to be better fitted to this type of scenario, but all the examples I've seen are using RabbitMQ. Wondering if it's possible/appropriate to do this using SQS, or if there's a better approach?

Thank you for taking the time to read this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit will extend the visibility timeout as long as the consumer is still running.

I believe SQS has an upper-limit of something like 12 hours, but you should look it up and find out.

Job Consumers have significantly greater requirements (sagas, temporary queues, etc.) and SQS is really annoying about not having auto-delete/expiring queues, so I'd stick to a regular consumer if you can swing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris! You are correct, the upper limit is 12 hours.That's interesting that masstransit extends the visibility timeout - in that case perhaps it makes sense to keep the visibility timeout small.

Comment: That depends, if it's too small, MassTransit has to extend it more often to avoid it expiring.